# Associations and Indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models,`community`, `profile`, `task`.
each community `has_many profiles` and each profile `has_many tasks`. 
Also the reverse: each task `belongs_to` profile and each profile `belongs_to` community. 
Question: What is the best way to index all of the profiles in one community? or all of the tasks in one profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create profiles that belongs to a community by

```
@community.profiles.create(:attr => val, :attr2 => val2, ...)
```

This will create a profile with a community_id of @community.id
You can then access all of the profiles that have a community_id of @community.id with

```
@community.profiles
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a `community`, `community.profiles` will give an array of all the `Profile` objects associated with the `Community` object.

Same way, from `profile` you'll get all of its tasks via `profile.tasks`.